# Java Telnet and SSH library

Tags: java, ssh, telnet

I need to make a Telnet and SSH connection in java (similar to the one we have in Putty).
Can you suggest me a good **Java library that support both Telnet and SSH**?

If somebody can also give me some code example it will be wonderful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need one library for both?!

SSH:
http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Telnet:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/

Comment: I need a secure telnet connection so a telnet trough an ssh

Comment: So establish a ssh tunnel with jsch and then use for telnet

Comment: I succeded to set the ssh tunnel using this [example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/PortForwardingL.java.html) but I have difficulty to use it for telnet. Have I to use the channel opened with:
*Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");*